# div floated to the left beside info goes down during window resize

Tags: html, css

I am making a mock website and the .sidebar div moves below the .info div after the window is resized a bit from its original position of being to the right of .info. I am trying to ensure that the sidebar remains where it is even if the window is resized to be smaller than it by but It is not working. Any help would be appreciated, here is the code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Sushi Restaurant</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
     <body>

      <header>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

       </header>

         <div class="info">
       <p>Food, in the end, in our own tradition, is something holy. <br>It's not about nutrients and calories.<br>
    It's about sharing. <br>It's about honesty. <br>It's about identity.</p>  
    <img src = "MomoSushi.jpg">
    </div>
      <div class ="sidebar">
    <img src = "download.png">    
      <p>265 Rock Rd, Condville DR 8182 9237</p>
      <h3>Opening Hours</h3>
     <ul>
      <li>Monday-9AM to 9PM</li>
      <li>Tuesday-9AM to 9PM</li>
       <li>Wednesday-9AM to 9PM</li>
       <li>Thursday-9AM to 9PM</li>
       <li>Friday-9AM to 9PM</li>

      </ul>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>

* {
    margin:auto;
    }
    body {
    font: bold 1.1em Courier;
    max-width:1600px;
    min-width:1000px;
      margin:auto;
    }

    header ul li{
    width:17%;
    min-width:18%;
    margin-top:4px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:15px;
    list-style-type:none;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    padding:15px 20px 5px;
    border-radius:0 0 15px 15px ;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #F5F5F5 inset;
    }
    ul {
    padding-left:0;

    }
    header {
    margin:auto;
    }
    a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:  #888888;
    }
    .info {

    min-width:60%;

    margin-top:30px;
    height:800px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:0;
    padding:left:0;
    background-color:   #E8E8E8;


    }
    .info p {
    width: 30%;
    float:left;
    line-height:3em;
      margin-top:50px;
      margin-left:100px;

    }
    .info img {
      position:fixed;
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
      margin-top:60px;

    margin-left: 150px;
     border-radius:50%;

    }



    .sidebar {
    min-width:30%;
    margin-left:5px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;


    }

    .sidebar li {
    display:block;
      margin-left:70px;
    }

    .sidebar h3 {
      margin-left:80px;
    }

    .sidebar p {
    margin-top:1px;
      margin-left:10px;
    margin-bottom:2px;

    }
```

Comment: I think this is those moments where an image would be needed.

Comment: I probably did not describe it very well but the .sidebar starts out as being to the right of the main info, kinda like how the available jobs on stack overflow are to the right of the fourm, but as a I minimize the screen, the sidebar ends up going under the main info div

Comment: I made a jsfiddle and I'm not seeing the problem. Please make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate the problem. Also edit the question and the title so it's more precise.

Comment: Do as wazz says or just post a picture of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happening because you have given **BODY TAG** 
`min-width:1000px;`  try increasing this to `min-width:1400px;`.

Don't you want this to be responsive? If Yes, you surely need to change the structure of HTML

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How did you know that making the min width 1400px would actually make it work. Also, how would I need to change the html structure to make this more responsive?

Comment: Hey! while making HTML structures try to bind every element inside a div, so that instead of giving margin/padding etc properties separately to every element you can give it to the parent element.
Go through the code structure I am attaching to get a understanding of the same

Js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/neel448/b7g4u1ro/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this apply css code :

.info { width:60%; }
.sidebar { width:30%; }